# Get text from Capybara node element

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

I am trying get the text value of table header with a classname in Capybara. I getting the node element in Capybara but I am not able to get the text content of the class when I use the `text` attribute. How can I get the text of the Capybara node element here?

**html.erb**

```
<% @tests.each do |test| %>        
    <th class="test_name_header"><%= test.name %></th>
<% end %>
```

**capybara_test.rb**

```
all(:css, '.test_name_header', :visible => false).each do |el|
      puts el.text
end
```

This code does not print the text of the element. Nothing is printed but when I `puts el` in the above code it prints the node element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs for `#text` - https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#text-instance_method - state that by default it only gets visible text. Since you're specifying `visible: false` in your `all` call I am assuming these headers are not actually visible on the page.  If that is the case then, as mentioned in the docs, you'd need to do

```
el.text(:all)
```

to get non-visible text.

Comment: @user001 The result of `all` includes Enumerable so you can use any of those methods on it. If you wanted to get all the texts in an array you should be able to  do something like `all(:css, '.test_name_header', visible: false).map { |el| el.text(:all) }`